# Meaning in the Tur's chapter numbers

Tags: number, tur

I've heard that the chapter in *Tur* (and, consequently, *Shulchan Aruch*) that deals with the *shofar* is number 586, the *gimatriya* of "*shofar*". I've also heard that the chapter number (240) for *tz'nius* (in *Orach Chayim*) matches that for *kibud av vaem* (in *Yore Dea*) as a way of teaching us that parents' *tz'nius* can lead to the children's *kibud* for them.

I'm seeking a list of such intentional chapter numberings in the *Tur*: those that were intended by the author to be meaningful. Can you please supply whichever you may know about?

Part of the reason I suspect they may really exist (besides, of course, that I've heard they do, as mentioned above) is that the *Tur*'s author refers often to *gimatriya* and acrostics in his short commentary on *Chumash*.

Note: I'm not seeking whatever interesting chapter-number facts you might happen to notice, or someone else noticed. Rather, I'm seeking **only** such chapter-number facts as some Judaism authority<sup>[1]</sup> has claimed were intentional on the part of the author of the *Tur*. **Every answer below should cite some source that not only indicates the interesting number fact but also claims that that was the author's intent.** (Thus, too, I hope that some answer(s) below will contain the *shofar* and *tz'nius* facts, since I currently have no source for them.)

---

<sup>[1] or a *Tur* authority, like an historian or a biographer</sup>

Comment: Even the examples of shofar and tznius seem to be at best mnemonics and drush and not the intent of the Tur. Do you have any basis to believe they were the original intention of the Tur?

Comment: @Yoni, they were examples of the sort of thing that — if they are indeed the author's intent — I'm looking for. I don't know that they were his intent (though I've heard the _tz'nius_ one is).

Comment: @msh210 I do not remember, but I too noticed a lot of similar things, impossible to be fortouitous coincidence. AGAV in mishna to you can find dozen in each massechet

Comment: @msh210 

אורח חיים תרעא
נר חנוכה מניחו על הפתח